# How to loop over CSV file and write each line in Write File activity?

Tags: tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

I am using TIBCO BW 6.5 designer, I am trying to read a large CSV file (having ; as separator). Below are some of my sample CSV file data:-

```
ORDER_NUMBER;CODE_NUMBER
A;014 53758
B;015 73495
C;016 67569
D;017 59390
```

I am trying to start reading from 2nd line i.e. "A;014 53758".
I am using "ParseData" activity which is placed inside a "Repeat" group as shown in Image below:-
[image]

The configuration of my "Repeat" group is below:-
[image]

The configuration of my "ParseData" is:-
[image]
[image]

In my WriteFile I have checked the "append" box, and I am writing as 'Text' in my file. The textContent for my WriteFile is :- 
concat($ParseData/Rows/Updates[$index]/ORDER_NUMBER, $ParseData/Rows/Updates[$index]/CODE_NUMBER , '&crlf;')

But when I run my project, the Write File only writes the first row and all the rest rows are blank.

Can anybody please help in rectifying what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Rudra

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

- ParseData activity input : startRecord should be 1 intead of $index + 1
- WriteFile activity input : concat($ParseData/Rows/Updates[1]/ORDER_NUMBER,
  -$ParseData/Rows/Updates[1]/CODE_NUMBER, '&crlf;') *(1 instead of $index)*
- You can uncheck the accumulate in the repeat loop

Comment: Thanks @losusovic . This helped in some way and by manipulating some logic I am able to get to solution.

Comment: one query, I am doing a POST operation in POSTMAN and I am using 2 headers also to hit one of my REST api. Can you please tell me where can I add these headers in my Send-HTTP-Request activity in BW 6.5 , if I want to perform same REST api call from BW 6.5?